# The bear is more afraid of you than you should be of it

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do not try outrun a bear.

> The bear is more afraid of you than you should be of it.

What does "be of it." here mean?

Comment: The bear is more afraid of you than you should be frightened by the bear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bear is more afraid of you than you should be (afraid) of it(the bear).